# How to group elements 5 by 5?

Tags: php

I have an array of about 40-something elements that I need grouped 5 by 5 like this:

```
<div class="five">
1
2
3
4
5
</div>
<div class="five">
6
7
8
9
10
</div>
```

What would be an elegant solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just call [`array_chunk`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php):

```
$numbers = range(1, 10);
$split = array_chunk($numbers, 5);
```

Comment: That is elegant! Worked great!

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
<?php
    $i = 0;
    foreach($array as $value){
        if($i % 5 == 0){echo '<div class="five">';}
        echo $value;
        if($i % 5 == 4){echo '</div>';}
        $i++;
    }
?>
```

Comment: This answer doesn't perhaps deserve the -1 it got (not mine), but you have to consider that the last div may contain less than 5 elements.

Comment: That's kinda how I did at first and you're right about that Jon. (I didn't give it -1 either)